# SonarQube with Jest Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube, jestjs

I've been trying to find out how to populate **SonarQube** with both my **Jest Unit Tests** and the **.net Unit Tests**.

I have a local version of *SQ 6.7* and all the latest versions of the Javascript and C# Plugins.

When it comes to Jest, I have the [`sonar-jest-reporter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-sonar-reporter) to export a `test-report.xml` file, and also have the `lcov.info` file being generated.

SonarQube is able to read the `lcov.info` and I see a coverage %, but no matter what I set as `include`/`exclude`, or tests path, it will not show the tests associated with the source file.

The file structure is all `.js` and the `.test.js` are in the same directory with each module.

Any help with pointing me in the correct direction, or others who have encountered and overcome this issue that would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want it to show the test files? The coverage is for your `.js` files not your `.tests.js`. Am I misunderstanding what you are trying to do? As far as I know the lcov file doesn't include data about which tests are associated with which source files. It only includes data on which lines/branches are covered by tests.

Comment: Where did you read this is possible in SonarQube?

Comment: I see the count of unit tests, but when you select it, they are blank. That's what I am trying to figure out. Isn't that a feature of SQ to see the coverage and the tests?

Answer (score 50):

Looks like I've figured out the way to make it work. The trick is to have both `sonar.sources` and `sonar.tests` point to same directory (because we have both tests and source in the same directory) then use `sonar.tests.inclusions` to pattern match test files with `.test.js` or `.spec.js` extension.

Here's a sample `sonar-project.properties` which assumes the following:

1. `src/components/Foo/Foo.jsx` the main component.
2. `src/components/Foo/Foo.spec.jsx` the test file.

```yaml
# Source
sonar.sources=src
# Where to find tests file, also src
sonar.tests=src
# But we get specific here
# We don't need to exclude it in sonar.sources because it is automatically taken care of
sonar.test.inclusions=src/**/*.spec.js,src/**/*.spec.jsx,src/**/*.test.js,src/**/*.test.jsx

# Now specify path of lcov and testlog
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/jest/lcov.info
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=coverage/jest/testlog.xml
```

Now your test files will also show up.

[*More information here*](https://github.com/3dmind/jest-sonar-reporter/issues/23)

Comment: I am using the Gradle plugin org.sonarqube (Version 3.3 at the moment) and had to modify the configuration a bit:
In the property sonar.test.inclusions I had to _remove_ the preceding `src/` as it seems that the plugin looked for tests with "src/src/..." in the path and complained that I didn't have that path for my tests. (Actually it didn't exactly complain about that, only read it from a stack trace).

Comment: when I set `sonar.sources` and `sonar.tests` to the same path I get this error:

##[error]ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
ERROR: File App.config can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files

Setting inclusion/exclusion patterns would require a lot of effort in trying matching all the cases. I'm talking about a Visual Studio solution with C# and NUnit for test runner, Javascript and React with Jest test runner.

Any suggestion how to go about it?

Comment: @RiccardoMerlin: you can post your question with full logs at Sonar Community https://community.sonarsource.com and Sonar people can help you.

Answer (score 1):

If coverage is not shown for your `js` file then try to use absolute path of your `lcov` or try to use the `lcov` path as `sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=./coverage/jest/lcov.info` Not sure if this help you or not but it worked for me.