# Sonarqube jest coverage report fails on expected XML format

Tags: javascript, jestjs, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I am using jest-sonar-reporter for the coverage as below:

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "The task runner packages for Gulp",
    "main": "gulpfile.js",
    "scripts": {
        ...
        "test": "jest --coverage",
        ...
    },
"devDependencies": {
   ...
    "jest": "26.0.1",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "2.0.0",
    ...
    },
    "jest": {
        ...
        "collectCoverage": true,
        "testResultsProcessor": "jest-sonar-reporter"
    },
    "jest-junit": {
        "suiteName": "jest tests",
        ...
    }
}
```

I have the test-report.xml file generated after *npm run test* as below:

**test-report.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testExecutions version="1">
  <file path="<path to>\AreaList.test.jsx">
    <testCase name="Description 1 " duration="6"/>
  </file>
  <file path="<path to>\selectors.search.test.js">
    <testCase name="Description 2 " duration="2"/>
  </file>
</testExecutions>
```

SonarScanner command:

> sonar-scanner.bat -Dsonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000" -Dsonar.projectKey="Project-A" -Dsonar.projectName="Project-A"  -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dsonar.testExecutionReportPaths="\test-report.xml"

I am getting error as:

```
INFO: Parsing <path to>\test-report.xml
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 5:29.011s
INFO: Final Memory: 15M/68M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
ERROR: Error during parsing of generic test execution report '<path to>\test-report.xml'. Look at the SonarQube documentation to know the expected XML format.
ERROR: Caused by: Line 3 of report refers to a file which is not configured as a test file: <path to>\AreaList.test.jsx
```

Am I missing any configuration?

Appreciate your response. Thank you.

Comment: First thing to try is to net search the non-specific part of your error message, which finds this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57466369/sonarqube-test-report-report-refers-to-a-file-which-is-not-configured-as-a-test . Does that help?

Comment: any solutions ?